# Magento 2 installation

Tags: magento2, error, installation

I am installing magento 2 by cloning from github through Git commands and by installing composer. when 'Composer install' command is entered in git, I got the error ,

"the lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json"

and it asks for authentication for downloading process.I entered the username and password of Github account. The problem is, it is not accepting it as valid credentials. My doubt is that what credentials should be given there? I also tried giving bitbucket credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to enter your credentials for logging into [magento.com](https://www.magento.com) / Magento Connect. The composer repository is hosted by Magento.

Comment: Yea I even tried that. It shows error like this-> " [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
 Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/composer
 /magento-composer-1.0.2.0.zip', aborting."

Comment: Are you sure you entered valid credentials? The error message kind of suggests otherwise. You can verify them on the site itself.

Comment: To reiterate what @RyanH. said did you set up valid credentials as specified here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Comment: Thank you so much guys. It wroked. I got my public key and private key from  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html as my credentials. Thank you once again